# How can I render Django Form with vuetify?

Tags: django, django-forms, vuetify.js

In our regular Django form we can render the form with something like this `{{form.username}}` and we specify the widget within the constructor of the form class like name, class, id, label, etc.

Now suppose that I have this form class

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput())
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    
    class Meta:
        fields = ['email', 'password']
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['email'].required = True
        self.fields['password'].required = True
```

How can I render it with vuetify components in template?

```
# example 
<v-text-field label="username"></v-text-field>
<v-select></v-select>
# something like that
```

Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

Looking for the exact same thing, i don't know if you managed to achieve what you wanted or if anybody got some hint.